# How to order scripts registered by ScriptManager's Register Script

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to alert `1` registering the scripts in this order

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "a", "alert(a);", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "b", "var a = 1;", true);
```

But doing this causes a error saying a is undefined.

I have different controls located in different parts of the page registering scripts, and some of them need to go first and others need to go last.

Is there a way to set order it will render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to define the order in which the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` methods are called. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx) for the `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` method (emphasis mine):

> **The script blocks are not guaranteed
>   to be output in the order they are
>   registered**. If the order of the script
>   blocks is important, **use a
>   StringBuilder object to gather the
>   scripts together in a single string**,
>   and then register them all in a single
>   client script block.

<strike>Also, you may want to define a different key (second parameter; `"a"`) for the second invocation of `RegisterStartupScriptBlock`, since a registered script is uniquely identified by its key. If you're calling this method with your parameters, `ScriptManager` won't register the second script, because another script with the same key (`"a"`) has already been registered.</strike>

Comment: The `a` key was a copy & paste mistake, fixed. Thanks.